# Add discriminator for embedded @ElementCollection table

Tags: java, hibernate, discriminator

Is there any way to add discriminator for embedded collection? Here is what I have

```
  @MappedSuperclass
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
    @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
    public abstract class EncounterDataInfo implements Serializable {

        @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
        private String name;

        @Column(length = 50, insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private String type;
}

@Embeddable
@DiscriminatorValue("DIAGNOSIS")
public class Diagnosis extends EncounterDataInfo {
}
@Embeddable
@DiscriminatorValue("MODIFIER")
public class Modifier extends EncounterDataInfo {
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENCOUNTER_DATA")
public class EncounterData extends AuditingEntity {
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Diagnosis.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "ENCOUNTER_DATA_INFO", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "encounter_data_id"))
    private List<Diagnosis> diagnoses;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Modifier.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "ENCOUNTER_DATA_INFO", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "encounter_data_id"))
    private List<Modifier> modifiers;
}
```

Currently EncounterData instance for both fields has all values from encounter_data_info table not depending on type. So it seems like discriminator value is not working? Why and how can I make it work?

Comment: Read the tag-descriptions before adding!

Comment: Hibernate doesn't support `@Embeddable` inheritance. See duplicate.